# Sorting an array of entries according to a fixed list/array of items

Tags: sorting, plugin-supersort

I want to sort an array of entries in a specific order. Every entry has a 'shoptype' and I want to show all entries for type A, than type B, than type C.

A partial solution would be to iterate over them `(if shoptype == A){ then show all A entries}` but than I can't write a conditonal around it to hide the title when there are no shops of type A.

So now I group them using the group twig filter and hide if the group has no items. But I can't sort them the way I like (it's not alphabetical, it's a fixed order that I want).

Idealy I would need something like this in supersort:

```
'SortAs', ['shoptype A', 'shoptype B', 'shoptype C']
```

So an array of strings that my shopType field can contain which my array is grouped by.

Comment: Hi Tom, this page might give you a good start: http://buildwithcraft.com/help/entry-archive

Answer (score 3):

**Edit: This strategy still works, but see my [updated answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/36981/689) for more up-to-date solution.**

Prior to SuperSort 3.1.0, you might achieve this by using the [`replace`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/replace.html) filter inside SuperSort's micro-template:

```
{% set foo = craft.entries.section('foo')... %}

{% set sortedFoo = foo | supersort('sortAs', '{ shopType | replace({
    'ShopType1': "A",
    'ShopType2': "B",
    'ShopType3': "C"
}) }') %}
```

The first parameter you pass to *SuperSort* specifies the **sort method**.

The second parameter provides a **value template** for the sorting function: Under the hood, the system parses `{ shopType | replace(...) }` — a Craft ['micro-template'](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#renderObjectTemplate-detail) — into `{{ object.shopType | replace(...) }}`. The plugin parses that template by passing in your array item as the `object` and uses the output value to sort by.)

*n.b. You need to specify that replacement list directly in the object template. Passing in a Twig variable doesn't work because the object template doesn't share the same context as the parent template.*

<strike>The syntax in your original question would actually not be a bad addition for use-cases like this; I'll look into adding something like that to SuperSort when I get some downtime.</strike>

**As of SuperSort 3.1.0, you [can now use a custom-order sort method](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/36981/689), similar to what you originally suggested.**

Comment: I wanted to implement this, but this doesn’t seem to work.. has the syntax changed since 2015?

Answer (score 1):

**As of SuperSort 3.1.0, you can use the `customOrderSort` and `customOrderSortAs` methods to accomplish this:**

```
{% set shops = craft.entries.section('shops')... %}

{% set customOrderList = [
    'SomeShopType',
    'AnotherShopType',
    'OneMoreShopType'
] %}

{% set sortedShops = shops
    | supersort('customOrderSortAs', as='{shopType}', comp=customOrderList) %}
```