# Custom sort order?

Tags: templating, sorting, plugin-supersort

I have a page that displays musicians grouped by their musical instrument. I am outputting them grouped by instrument, but I have been asked to sort the instrument groups by a custom order specified by the client. Not alphabetical, but a specified order. How should I handle this? I was using .orderBy(‘instrument asc’) in the query to get them in alphabetical order. Would I be creating an array and then assigning keys to them for the order I want and then order by the numerical keys or something? I haven’t been able to figure it out yet. Code snippet below:

```
  {% set relatedMusicians=craft.entries.section('bios’)
     .relatedTo(entry)
     .orderBy('instrument asc')
     .with(['bioPhoto'])
     .all() 
  %}
```

Comment: What field type do you use for _instrument_?

Comment: Plain text; I thought of a dropdown but there are lots of possible instruments and there might be more added down the road, so plain text is what I did.

Comment: I'd recommend another field type if at all possible. Categories or even related entries (structure) will give you far more flexibility than a plain text field. Are you still in a position to change that?

Comment: I could conceivably change the field type, yes. That being said, please note that each musical group’s leader wants their instrumental groups in a different order, so the clarinets might be at the top of one group’s list and the bottom of another’s... so setting up a structure might not do the trick...? Or maybe there is a way? I’m quite open to suggestions... I saw this old post about a SuperSort plugin and I wonder if it could be a possible start... https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11050/sorting-an-array-of-entries-according-to-a-fixed-list-array-of-items?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I would like to thank Michael Rog for supplying an answer at this similar question about SuperSort:

[Sorting an array of entries according to a fixed list/array of items](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11050/sorting-an-array-of-entries-according-to-a-fixed-list-array-of-items/36981#36981)

The code that lets me sort by instrument in any order I want:

```
  {% set relatedMusicians = craft.entries.section('bios').relatedTo(entry)
  .with(['bioPhoto'])
  .all() 
  %}

        {% set sortAsList = [
          "violin",
          "viola",
          "cello",
         ] %}

{% set sortedMusicians= relatedMusicians
| supersort('customOrderSortAs', as='{instrument}', comp=sortAsList) %}
```